# How to get meld window to reappear?

Tags: mac, meld

On mac, sometimes when one runs `meld`, the window doesnt appear. I suspect this is something to do with using it on an external monitor sometime, and the application has somehow memorized its position on the external monitor, and is displaying itself on a now non-existent external monitor. How to delete the meld saved state, so the window appears?

Answer (score 0):

To purge the meld saved state:

```
rm -Rf Library/Saved\ Application\ State/org.gnome.meld.savedState/
```